# Current model is incompatible with old migrations

Tags: laravel, database-design, laravel-migrations

I have following sitation (I will describe it as history line):

1. I setup project witch `User` model (and `users` table) with migration file **A**
2. After some time i add user_modules table many-to-many and I was force to initialize this array during schama update in migration file **B**. I do it by

   ```
   User::chunk(100, function($users) {
       foreach ($users as $user) {
           $user->userModule()->create();
       }
   });
   ```
3. After some time i need to update `User` model and table by add soft-delete (column delete_at) in migration file **C** and field `$dates=['deleted_at']` in `User` model.
4. Then I develop system and add more migrations but at some point new developer join to our team and he must build DB schema from scratch so he run `php artisan:migrate` but he get error in migration file **B**:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException (42S22)]
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'users.deleted_at' in 'where clause' (SQL:      select * from `users`
>   where `users`.`deleted_at` is null order by `users`.`id` asc limit 100
>   off     set 0)

So the current `User` model is incompatible witch migration file **B**

How to deal with that situation?

Where I made mistake and what to do to prevent such situation in future?

Comment: The problem is that even if I move `user_modules` initialisation code to last migration file, then in future User model will be updated and again it will be incompatible with old migration... :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of Soft Deletes.  When you add the trait SoftDeletes to a model, it will automatically add `where users.deleted_at is null` to all queries.  The best way to get around this is to add `withTrashed()` to your query in migration B.

To do this, change your query in migration B to look like the following.  This should remove the part where it's trying to access the non existent `deleted_at` column.  This migration, after all, is not aware that you want to add soft deletes later on, so accessing all users, including those that are trashed, makes perfect sense.

```
User::withTrashed()->chunk(100, function($users) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $user->userModule()->create();
    }
});
```

You could always comment out the SoftDelete trait on the user model before running the migrations also, but that's a temporary fix since you'll need to explain it to all future developers.  Also, it can be very handy to run `php artisan migrate:fresh` sometimes.  You don't want to have to remember to comment out the trait each time, so adding `withTrashed()` seems like the most desirable solution to me.

As a final note, I highly suggest **NOT** adding seeds to your migrations.  Migrations should **ONLY** be used for schema changes.  In cases like this, I would use a console command, or a combination of console commands.

For example, you could make a console command that gets triggered by `php artisan check:user-modules`.  Within this command, you could have the following which will create a user module only if one does not yet exist.

```
User::chunk(100, function($users) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if (!$user->userModule()->exists()) {
            $user->userModule()->create();
        }
    }
});
```

You should be able to run this command at any time since it won't overwrite existing user modules.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer: In such situation when we need to generate or transform some data after db schema change - we **should NOT use Models** (which can independently change in future) but instead use [inserts/updates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#inserts):

```
DB::table('users')->chunkById(100, function ($users) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        DB::table('user_modules')->insert(
            ['user_id' => $user->id, 'module_id' => 1]
        );
    }
});
```

As it is written in [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/seeding), seeders are designed for data seeding with test data but not for data transformation - so migration files are probably good place to put transformation code (which can generate or change some production data in DB after schema update)

> Laravel includes a simple method of seeding your database with test data using seed classes.

Comment: This would work, but if it's still in your migration files, you can do better, imo.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your old migration queries

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope;
   
User::withoutGlobalScope(new SoftDeletingScope())
```